# VB.NET Array of structure: No .push_back available?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, structure, push-back

I have defined a structure in VB.NET and created an array from it:

```
Public Struct MyStruct
    Dim SomeValue As String
    Dim SomeOtherValue As Double
End Struct

Public MyArr() As MyStruct
```

I am wondering if there is no .push_back function available for the array under VB.NET as it would be in C++.

Currently I am redimming + preserving the array and assign a new array member to the new empty member which is quite typing-intensive and which is not so cool in aspects of a readability:

```
 Redim Preserve MyArr(0 To MyArr.GetUpperbound(0) +1)
 MyArr(MyArr.GetUpperbound(0)) = someNewItem
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Did you try a generic list of MyStruct? [List(Of T) Class reference @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I meant:

```
Dim lst As New List(Of MyStruct)
lst.Add(someNewItem)
```

Assuming you have declared this:

```
Public Structure MyStruct
  Dim SomeValue As String
  Dim SomeOtherValue As Double
End Structure
```

If you absolutely need to be working with arrays, try this:

```
MyArr = MyArr.Union({someNewItem}).ToArray
```

Answer (score 1):

Structs are mainly used for performance, but as you are using `Redim Preserve` that is obviously not the reason in your case.

Unless you have a specific reason to use a struct, you should use a class instead, and use a list instead of an array:

```
Public Class MyClass

  Dim SomeValue As String
  Dim SomeOtherValue As Double

  Public Sub MyClass(value As String, other As Double)
    SomeValue = value
    SomeOtherValue = other
  End Sub

End Struct

Public MyList As New List(Of MyClass)
```

Now you can easily add items to the list:

```
MyList.Add(New MyClass("Answer", 42))
```

Comment: Using arrays of structs is just a bad habit of mine. I should really get rid of that now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The C++ Standard Template Library [vector class](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/) provides a [push_back](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/) method. A C++ vector encapsulates a resizeable array.

As pointed out by @Neolisk, the .Net equivalent of a generic resizeable array is a [List Of T](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (the non-generic version is the more aptly named [ArrayList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

You can use a struct with a List of T, there is no need to define a class.